# May I know whether the two sentences have the same meaning?

Tags: present-tense

1) They *come* to help the boys.

2) They *have come* to help the boys.

Answer (score 1):

Both are good English, but they have different meanings.

The form in the present indicates the recurrence of something that is frequent or regular. "They come to mow the lawn" would describe the presence of a landscaping crew that come on a regular and frequent basis to mow the lawn during the growing season.

The form in the present perfect indicates an occurrence without implying or denying recurrence. Thus, the present perfect is the more usual form because it is used for non-recurring action and for recurring ones when there is no desire or need to indicate recurrence.

Comment: I've seen the form described in point **1** being used even without the recurrence of an event. For example - '*What brings you here?*', '*I come here to make peace*'. I think perhaps this style was used often in old-fashioned or very formal English.

Comment: I admit that I was talking about current US usage.